# Amazon Corretto supports applets?

Tags: applet, corretto

I have a few web-pages that run Java applets so hope someone can help to answer this.

Does Amazon Coretto supports applets?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corretto8 does not currently support applets. This is being tracked in this Github issue:

https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/issues/5

Comment: Thank you so much for the info